# How do i make the program accept the second input before the first one while keeping the delay?

Tags: c++

If i press A then B quickly, i would like the program to display
Case B before
Case A while still keeping the delay on Case A
but no matter how i do it after pressing A then B the program still waits 2 seconds for Case A to finish.
What should i do?
Also i apologize for my poor english skills.

```
        if (_kbhit()){
        
        
        switch (getch()){
            case 'a':
                Sleep(2000);
                cout << "AAAAA";
                break;
                
            case 'b':
                cout << "BBBBB";
                break;
            
        }

}
```

Comment: Without using threads or separate processes, all programs are essentially serial, and handle all events in the order they arrive. If `a` happens before `b` then you can't change the order of that. To accomplish what you want you either have to add parallelism to your program in some way, or add extra checks for `b` in the handler for `a`.

Comment: Or you can read the current time, when *a* is pressed and get the keyboard input without blocking (or with timeout), then you can react to time events in addition to key or presses.